# Return variable in view after response ajax laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel-4

I'm new in laravel and sory for my bad english.
I'm trying to response ajax variable in my controller into view, but my view always response error message " **Undefined variable: useredit** " in firstly load page.

My code is below:

html

```
@foreach($user as $users)
{{ $users->USER_NAME }}
<a href="#"  onClick="showHint('{{ $users->USER_NAME }}');" >edit</a>
<input type="text" value="{{  $useredit->USER_NAME }}" >
@endforeach
```

ajax

```
        function showHint(str){
        var oke = str
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: 'http://localhost/examake/user-management/edit/'+oke,
            })
    }
```

route

```
Route::get('/user-management/edit/{USER_NAME}',  'UserManagementController@edit');
```

controller

```
        public function edit($id)
{
    if(Request::ajax()){
        return'asd';
        return View::make('usermanagement')
        ->with('useredit', UserManagement::where('USER_NAME','=',$id)->first());
    }
}
```

As you can see. in my view has a useredit variable and undeclared value, but controller return this variable in view.

Any thoughts, suggestions and / or ideas are greatly welcomed and appreciated.
thanks before

Comment: Mostly this type of error happens when the variable is empty or null. Try to check the variable before printing or assign a default value for a variable.

Answer (score 0):

why you have wrtitten this line of code in controller`s edit() function?

```
 return'asd';
```

when you made a request it will return 'asd'. and please past what error you are getting ?

Comment: this return return 'asd' is only as a marker if ajax I created is a right code up to the controller. and ajax script runs without error on the controller.
it's just that when I load the page for the first time an error occurs in the blade template "Undefined variable: useredit"
thanks for the response Anand